# What is the unit of measurement used for radius in the circle class of Source code: matplotlib.patches

Tags: python, matplotlib

Looking at the circle class in source code: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/matplotlib/patches.html#Circle.set_radius

I am trying to identify if the radius is in miles, m or km. How do I check it.

Circle is already drawn and i tried to manually estimate looking at the circle but dont think this is a good way of verification

```
class Circle(Ellipse):
    """
    A circle patch.
    """
    def __str__(self):
        pars = self.center[0], self.center[1], self.radius
        fmt = "Circle(xy=(%g, %g), radius=%g)"
        return fmt % pars

    @docstring.dedent_interpd
    def __init__(self, xy, radius=5, **kwargs):
        """
        Create true circle at center *xy* = (*x*, *y*) with given
        *radius*.  Unlike :class:`~matplotlib.patches.CirclePolygon`
        which is a polygonal approximation, this uses Bezier splines
        and is much closer to a scale-free circle.

        Valid kwargs are:
        %(Patch)s

        """
        Ellipse.__init__(self, xy, radius * 2, radius * 2, **kwargs)
        self.radius = radius

[docs]    def set_radius(self, radius):
        """
        Set the radius of the circle

        Parameters
        ----------
        radius : float
        """
        self.width = self.height = 2 * radius
        self.stale = True


[docs]    def get_radius(self):
        """
        Return the radius of the circle
        """
        return self.width / 2.


    radius = property(get_radius, set_radius)
```

Expected: Radius should be in miles
Actual: Unclear about the unit measurement used for radius

Comment: Why would there need to be a unit? The radius, as well as x/y values, are just numbers. The maths is identical irrespective of the unit chosen, so no sane geometry library will tie values to specific units. In effect, the unit is "unit". If x is 10, it is 10 units, if y is 120, it is 120 units, and if the radius if 6.28, then it is 6.28 units.

Comment: Is the radius in miles, km or meters? How do I verify that

Comment: It is not in any of those things: the parameters are just pure numbers.

Comment: What @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is saying is that it is in whatever units you have assigned to those numbers. The library does not deal in units because the math is the same. If you have a circle with a radius of 10 miles or 10 kilometers the math will be the same. You as the user have to know what units you put in to know what you get out, and if you need to change units (as in you are given something in km and need it in miles) then you need to perform the conversion and know which units are which at any given time.

Comment: ax.add_patch(Circle((-118.22191509999999, 34.0431494), 5, fill = False ))
Does not this take the latitude and longitude as a center and construct a 5 mile radius around it. Are you saying this is just a point on the graph and radius is 5 units from this numerical point?

Comment: that is the correct explanation: it's just the 2D coordinate x=-118.2... and y=34.0... on a graph centered at (0,0), with a radius of 5 units.

Comment: Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans makes complete sense. Thank you for clearing the confusion. I was just reading the API documentation and trying to identify if the radius used in getting the radius method is miles or meters.

Comment: Patches per se have no units attached to them. Once you add a patch to an axes it will take the data units of the axes. The data units of the axes are of course also the user's choice, but existing axes may have meaningful units defined implicitely (say the axes label already says "kilometers", then the viewer would expect the numbers on the axes to denote "kilometers").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mold your implementation like getting distance from two points it will give you distance between two points and here you go for radius.

```
import math
p1 = [-118.22191509999999, 34.0431494]
p2 = [-118.13458169630128, 34.04311852494086]
distance = math.sqrt( ((p1[0]-p2[0])**2)+((p1[1]-p2[1])**2) )
self.ax1.add_patch(Circle((-118.22191509999999, 34.0431494), 0.08733340915635142, fill=False))
```

0.08733340915635142 is your distance as well as radius.